# Django: how to zip all html/css/js files?

Tags: django, html, css, web

I'm building my new website using the great Django framework and I would like to bundle all

js/css/html together for external design work.

Do you know any tool that might come up handy?

Or maybe there is another option for external designer to work on my project?

10x

Comment: How is this a programming question? What's the problem here? Are you asking how to compress your files? Are you asking how to structure your files? Are you're asking for a good tool recommendation (also not the right place for this)? Please edit your question to make it clearer

Comment: Are you asking about source control maybe?  There are a number of hosted providers that could work for you.  You do need to clarify your question, though.

Answer (score 2):

The normal option is to use a [revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) which not only will let you share the needed code but also continuously integrate the changes without conflicts when one of the developers changes something. Of course compression of resources is automatically done by those software.

No serious developer, even alone, works without such a source control software.

There are online solutions if you can't set up a server, for example https://github.com/

Comment: I don't want to share my code with external freelancer that does not know Django at all. I really don;t know how the design can be outsourced to external freelancer.

Comment: You're not required to share everything.

Comment: Please advice, i was thinking to give all html/js/css to the freelancer designer and that's all.

Comment: If you don't want to setup complex rights, you can define a project for just the design part and share it on a service like github.